# Formating issues with Atom Beautify

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, atom-beautify

I'm frustrated with the behavior of Atom Beautify.

Actual Behavior:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function MyComponent() {
    return ( <div>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div> )
}
```

Expected Behavior

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function MyComponent() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    )
}
```

How can I get this formatting by default?

Comment: This site's intended use is for specific development issues with coding. This is a tool question and not covered by the terms of use. Please see the Code of Conduct: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" specifically says "... software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Atom is such a tool and we cover questions relating to its use and behavior. The code of conduct page does not apply to this question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question needs more detail. What did you change? Without that information, answers can revisit things you tried, which wastes everyone's time, or someone might be able to see what you did wrong with your attempt. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: I noticed the Atom "react" plugin shows a little video under "JSX Reformatting" demonstrating the formatting you're looking for, and that Beautify doesn't show react in its list of supported languages.

Answer (score 0):

Atom's Beautify has a configuration file that you can modify to get your desired settings I believe, if you go to the package and click on settings you should be able to make some changes there to get what you need

Comment: I have attempted tweaking some of those settings in the sub-category JSX within the package settings. Nothing in here seems to affect the beautification in the way I'm asking.